# Not able to install gdb 7.5

Tags: gdb

I am trying to install gdb 7.5 
My OS env is : Linux ddkhost 2.6.18-53.el5PAE #1 SMP Wed Oct 10 16:48:18 EDT 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
 I am following these steps:

`./configure`

`make`

now it is running recursively endless.

```
configure: creating ./config.status
CONFIG_FILES=Makefile CONFIG_HEADERS= /bin/sh ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile

make: Warning: File `Makefile.in' has modification time 1.9e+08 s in the future
CONFIG_SHELL="/bin/sh" /bin/sh ./config.status --recheck
running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh /bin/sh ./configure --no-create --no-recursion
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for PWL_handle_timeout in -lpwl... no
checking for version 0.11 (revision 0 or later) of PPL... no
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG...
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison... bison
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... m4
checking for flex... flex
checking for flex... flex
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking for expect... expect
checking for runtest... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... host tool
checking where to find the target as... host tool
checking where to find the target cc... host tool
checking where to find the target c++... host tool
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... host tool
checking where to find the target dlltool... host tool
checking where to find the target gcc... host tool
checking where to find the target gcj... host tool
checking where to find the target gfortran... host tool
checking where to find the target gccgo... host tool
checking where to find the target readelf... host tool
checking where to find the target strip... host tool
checking where to find the target windres... host tool
checking where to find the target windmc... host tool
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether -fkeep-inline-functions is supported... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
CONFIG_FILES=Makefile CONFIG_HEADERS= /bin/sh ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile

make: Warning: File `Makefile.in' has modification time 1.9e+08 s in the future
CONFIG_SHELL="/bin/sh" /bin/sh ./config.status --recheck
running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh /bin/sh ./configure --no-create --no-recursion
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
```

and so on.......

What is the reason?

Comment: Clock not properly set? Files on NFS (and clocks not synced)?

Comment: so how to set that..?

Comment: Well. Set your system clock properly (through some GUI or date command). Try modifying timestamp on all project files, by something like find . -exec touch {} \;

Answer (score 0):

From:

```
make: Warning: File `Makefile.in' has modification time 1.9e+08 s in the future
```

it indeed seems like your system clock is not synced up with your NFS server like @drank0 commented. Assuming you have root, try setting the time via NTP first:

```
ntpdate -s ntp.pool.org
```

If that doesn't work, just set the date like:

```
date -s 'May 23, 2013'
```